# Should FAQ#dontask explain "too localized"

Tags: discussion, site-scope

While questions can be reported/closed for being too localized, the FAQ only seems to address overly broad scopes, and not too localized ones.

Should the FAQ be updated to explain these guidelines?

Answer (score 2):

The FAQ already explains too localized [here](https://apple.stackexchange.com/faq#close):

> Common reasons a question may be closed include…
>
> too localized This question is unlikely to help any future visitors;
>   it is only relevant to a small geographic area, a specific moment in
>   time, or an extraordinarily narrow situation that is not generally
>   applicable to the worldwide audience of the internet.

Comment: Too localized is also something that should be construed with as open a mind as possible. Here is a good starting point for deciding if something is truly too local in a bad sense for the site: [What questions should be closed with reason “too localized”?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/4818/what-questions-should-be-closed-with-reason-too-localized)